# Filter in ejs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

So I've been trying to make a filter that filters the products by the user that created them, there are two posibilties role "admin" or role "member".

**This is the Controller**

```
exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
  let filter = { userId: req.user._id }; // por defecto, solo mostrar productos del usuario autenticado
  const products = await Product.find().populate('userId');

  // si el usuario es admin, no aplicar filtro de usuario
  if (req.user.role === 'admin') {
    filter = {};
  }

  // Busca todos los usuarios
  User.find({})
    .then(users => {
      // Busca los productos según el filtro aplicado
      return Product.find(filter)
        .then(products => {
          res.render('admin/products', {
            prods: products,
            pageTitle: 'Admin Products',
            path: '/admin/products',
            users: users // Pasa los usuarios a la vista
          });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
};
```

**This is the view .ejs**

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/product.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css">
</head>

<body>
    <%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs') %>

    <% if( role === "admin") { %>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn">Created by</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#" id="me-link">Me</a>
            <a href="#" id="others-link">Others</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    <main class="<%= role %>">
        <% if (prods.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="grid">
            <% let userIds = []; %>
            <% for (let product of prods) { %>
            <article class="card product-item <%= product.userId.role %>">
                <header class="card__header">
                    <h1 class="product__title">
                        <%= product.title %>
                    </h1>
                </header>
                <div class="card__image">
                    <img src="/<%= product.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= product.title %>">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h2 class="product__price">
                        <%= product.price %> €
                    </h2>
                    <p class="product__description">
                        <%= product.description %>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__actions">
                    <a href="/admin/edit-product/<%= product._id %>?edit=true" class="btn">Edit</a>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%= product._id %>" name="productId">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%= product.userId %>" name="userId">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                    <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="deleteProduct(this)">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </article>

             <% userIds.push(product.userId); } %> 
        </div>

        <% let userRolesIds = []; %>
        <% for (let user of users) { %>
            userRolesIds.push({ role: '<%= user.role %>', id: '<%= user._id %>' });
            
                     <% } %>
        <% } else { %>
        <h1>No Products Found!</h1>
        <% } %>
    </main>
    <%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
    <script src="/js/admin.js"></script>
    <script>
        const meLink = document.querySelector('#me-link');
        const othersLink = document.querySelector('#others-link');
        const main = document.querySelector('main');
        let role = '';

        meLink.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            role = 'admin';
            main.classList.remove('member');
            main.classList.add('admin');
        });

        othersLink.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            role = 'member';
            main.classList.remove('admin');
            main.classList.add('member');
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

*The big problem is that products and users are in a diferent collection for obvious reasons so the reference between them in the userId that created the product.*

I expect to hide the products that were maked by role "member" when I click in the "Me" button and vicerversa when I click in the "Others" button.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+by+role+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.